# Expression grammar with different types of data

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, context-free-grammar

I'm writing an interpreter for a small language that deals with vectors. I'm using Flex and Bison.

Vectors are declared with the following notation:

v := <1.4, -2.2, 7>

So, their components can also include negative numbers. Supported operations on those vectors are addition, subtraction and scalar multiplication. So you cannot add a vector and scalar, you cannot subtract a vector and a scalar, but you can multiply a vector and a scalar.

Since negative numbers are supported, my lexical analyzer uses the following regular expression to match numbers:

```
[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)? {yylval.somedub = atof(yytext); return NUMBER;}
```

The problem occurs when an expression of the following format is to be parsed (exactly the same problem with a plus, of course):

```
v-2*v
```

The way it should be parsed is: `vector minus (number times vector)`. But, as soon as flex sees -2 it will interpret it as a number, so I get `vector (number) times vector` which, of course, makes no sense. On the other hand if you were to write `v - 2*v` it works fine, since there's a space between the `-` and the `2`. The expression part of my grammar looks like this (I'm not going to copy the entire code because it's pretty big):

```
expression:
    expression '+' level_1
    | expression '-' level_1
    | level_1

level_1:
    NUMBER '*' level_1
    | level_1 '*' NUMBER
    | level_2

level_2:
    '(' expression ')'
    | vector //parses the whole <a, b, c, ..> notation, irrelevant for the problem
```

I've also declared +, - and * as left-associative using

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*'
```

So how would I go about fixing this problem? I don't know whether I need to change the associativity somehow or maybe reconstruct the whole grammar.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to allow stuff like `(1.0-0.5)*<3+1,2+7,<1,2,3>> + <1>`?

Comment: No, there aren't going to be any number expressions. So no (1+2)*vector, but of course something like 2*(vector + vector) is allowed. Also, vectors are always stated with just one number per coordinate, no expressions inside allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `-2` is recognized as a single `NUMBER` token, that means the parser will see `v-2` as a name followed by a number and at that point, there's not really anything you can do to get the parse you want. So instead `-2` should be recognized as two tokens: a minus sign followed by a number.

To achieve this, you can simply remove `[+-]?` from your regex for numbers (I'm assuming you already have a rule to recognize `+` and `-` on their own).

Now you only need to adjust your grammar to allow `-` or `+` followed by a number (or by any expression if you also want to allow something like `-v` or `-(2+3)`).

Comment: You could also use a start condition to decide when `-` is part of a number. That would be useful if you wanted to exclude things like `<3, - /* Misplaced comment */ 7.2, 4>`

Comment: That had occurred to me but I thought maybe it was "too simple" to be the right solution. Anyway I've tried it that way, and it works now. Thanks.